# Similar fields in DTO

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I want to create a DTO. The DTO will be used to map HTTP request to a REST webservice in spring. My controller looks like this:

```java
RequestMapping( value = DmsRestSvcApi.DOCUMENT_SEARCH_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE } )
public List<DocSearchResponse> getDocumentInfoJson( @Validated @RequestBody DocSearchRequest oDocSearchRequest ) throws Exception {
    // do something
}
```

In the above signature the `DocSearchRequest` is the DTO I want to create. The DTO has some fields like:

```java
private String searchCriteria1;
private String searchCriteria2;
/*
  .
  .
  .
 */
private String searchCriteria20;

// setters and getters.
```

Do we have a better way to implement the DTO? One thing to keep in mind is Spring uses reflection to set the values from the request to the DTO.

Comment: Why don't you use a List for the Criterias?

Comment: i can try that but not sure if spring will be able to map the request to the body using reflections.

Comment: If you provide the values in the JSON as list, then it will be able to do that.

Comment: You can use a `List` as @dunni suggested, or you can create a simple class containing private fields with public getters and setters, or you could also use a `Map<String, Object>` and use `get("searchCriteria1")` etc methods to get the values.

Comment: @dunni and Federico I implement a List and in my request i send my criteria as a coma separated. I all works as charm... thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A List of cafeterias solved the problem. I have to send the request as a comma separated value ans Spring takes care of mapping. Same can be done for the Response.

Answer (score -1):

`Do we have a better way to implement the DTO.`

There is no business logic in DTO. It looks like you don't have too. It should represent the state of object . It should have private instance fields and their getters/setters. Basically should follow the encapsulation/abstraction.